# Find the K'th element of a list using foldr

Tags: haskell, fold

I try to implement own safe search element by index in list. 
I think, that my function have to have this signature:

```
safe_search :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
safe_search xs n = foldr iteration init_val xs n
iteration = undefined
init_val = undefined
```

I have problem with implementation of iteration. I think, that it has to look like this:

```
safe_search :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
safe_search xs n = foldr iteration init_val xs n
    where
    iteration :: a -> (Int -> [a]) -> Int -> a
    iteration x g 0 = []
    iteration x g n = x (n - 1)
    init_val :: Int -> a
    init_val = const 0
```

But It has to many errors. My intuition about haskell is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have

```
safe_search :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
safe_search xs n = foldr iteration init_val xs n
```

if `null xs` holds, `foldr iteration init_val []` => `init_val`, so

```
init_val n
```

must make sense. Nothing to return, so

```
             = Nothing
```

is all we can do here, to fit the return type.

So `init_val` is a function, `:: Int -> Maybe a`. By the definition of `foldr`, this is also what the "recursive" argument to the combining function is, "coming from the right":

```
iteration x r
```

but then this call must also return just such a function itself (again, by the definition of `foldr`, `foldr f z [a,b,c,...,n] == f a (f b (f c (...(f n z)...)))`, `f :: a -> b -> b` i.e. it must return a value of the same type as it gets in its 2nd argument ), so

```
               n | n==0 = Just x
```

That was easy, 0-th element is the one at hand, `x`; what if `n > 0`?

```
                 | n>0  = ... (n-1)
```

Right? Just one more step left for you to do on your own... :) It's not `x` (the list's element) that goes on the dots there; it must be a function. We've already received such a function, as an argument...

To see what's going on here, it might help to check the case when the input is a one-element list, first,

```
safe_search [x] n = foldr iteration init_val [x] n
                  = iteration x init_val n
```

and with two elements,

```
            [x1, x2] n = iteration x1 (iteration x2 init_val) n
        --               iteration x  r                       n
```

Hope it is clear now.

*edit:* So, this resembles the usual `foldr`-based implementation of `zip` fused with the  descending enumeration from `n` down, indeed encoding the more higher-level definition of

```
foo xs n = ($ zip xs [n,n-1..]) $ 
                        dropWhile ((>0) . snd) >>>
                        map fst >>>
                        take 1 >>> listToMaybe
         = drop n >>> take 1 >>> listToMaybe $ xs
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about a few things.

1. What type should `init_val` have?
2. What do you need to do with `g`? `g` is the trickiest part of this code. If you've ever learned about continuation-passing style, you should probably think of both `init_val` and `g` as continuations.
3. What does `x` represent? What will you need to do with it?

I wrote up an [explanation](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldl_as_foldr_alternative) some time ago about how the definition of `foldl` in terms of `foldr` works. You may find it helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use standard `foldr` pattern, because it is easier to read and understand the code, when you use standard functions:

1. `foldr` has the type `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> [a] -> b -> [b]`,
   where third argument `b` is the accumulator `acc` for elements of your list `[a]`.
2. You need to stop adding elements of your list `[a]` to `acc` after you've added desired element of your list. Then you take `head` of the resulting list `[b]` and thus get desired element of the list `[a]`.
3. To get `n`'th element of the list `xs`, you need to add `length xs - n` elements of `xs` to the accumulator `acc`, counting from the end of the list.
4. But where to use an iterator if we want to use the standard `foldr` function to improve the readability of our code? We can use it in our accumulator, representing it as a tuple `(acc, iterator)`. We subtract `1` from the `iterator` each turn we add element from our initial list `xs` to the `acc` and stop to add elements of `xs` to the `acc` when our `iterator` is equal `0`.
5. Then we apply `head . fst` to the result of our `foldr` function to get the desired element of the initial list `xs` and wrap it with `Just` constructor.
6. Of course, if `length - 1` of our initial list `xs` is less than the index of desired element `n`, the result of the whole function `safeSearch` will be `Nothing`.

Here is the code of the function `safeSearch`:

```
safeSearch :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe a
safeSearch n xs
  | (length xs - 1) < n = Nothing
  | otherwise           = return $ findElem n' xs
  where findElem num =
          head .
          fst .
          foldr (\x (acc,iterator) ->
                   if iterator /= 0
                      then (x : acc,iterator - 1)
                      else (acc,iterator))
                ([],num)

        n' = length xs - n
```

Comment: `length` is usually a bad idea, and this is no exception.